# make next contenteditable element editable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html, contenteditable

I have a following structure

```
<div>
<ul id='t1'>
  <li id='l1' contenteditable='true' class='editable'> Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li id='l2' contenteditable='true' class='editable'> Lorem ipsum </li>
  <li id='l3' contenteditable='true' class='editable'> Lorem ipsum </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

What I want here is when the user edits say li l3 and when he hits enter I want to add new li with contenteditable = true and setfocus on the new li so that user can start typing there. 
I was able to add a new entry on enter by but couldn't set focus on it.

**Update**

```
 if(e.keyCode == 13){//enter Key or tab key 9
    e.preventDefault();
    var taskId = this.id;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'update_current',
        type : 'put',
        success : function(resp){ //resp is the new li tag
          var li =  this_is_current_elemtn;
          jQuery(li).append(resp);

          //$('#t1 .editable').each(function(){
            // $(this).attr('editable', 'false');
          //});
          console.log(jQuery(li).next());

           jQuery(li).next().focus();
         // $('#t1 .editable').each(function(){
         //    $(this).attr('contentEditable', 'true');
         // });
        }
    });
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If you have created the element then you could just use $("#younewelement").focus();

Comment: tried with focus and select , but the still the current contenteditable stays in focus, does not shift focus to newly added element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/t7GJc/

```
$('#t1').on('keydown', 'li', function(e){
    var c = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if(c === 13){
        e.preventDefault();                    
        if($(this).is($('#t1 li:last'))){
            $(this).after($('<li id="l'+($('#t1 li').length + 1)+'" contenteditable="true"/>'));
        }
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Ross does it not work like you want it to in the jsfiddle demo? If not why?

Comment: it was my html structure that was causing issue for me i guess, any way it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

i know it`s a bit late but anyway, if you add the contenteditable='true' to the parent ol or ul, it does the trick! :)

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WUExt/1/)

```
    $("ul").on("keyup", "li",function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
     var elem = $( "<li contenteditable='true'> Lorem ipsum </li>").appendTo ($(this).parent());
         elem.focus();
}
        return false;

    });​
```